If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then there are $x, y \in E$ such that $|x - y|$ is irrational
This is a question for my real analysis HW:

Show that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set with $m(E) > 0$, then there exist $x, y \in E$ such that $|x-y|$ is irrational.

Here is my solution (via contradiction):
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\forall$ $x, y \in E$, we have that $|x - y| \in \mathbb{Q}$. Thus, as the difference of a rational and an irrational is irrational, $E$ consists of either all rational elements or irrational elements. If $E$ consists of all rational elements, we have a contradiction as $m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$. If $E$ consists of all irrational elements, they must all different by a rational, so $E$ is nowhere dense and thus has measure $0$, a contradiction.
The only thing I am worried about is the final line. Does the fat cantor set make my argument faulty?

A set consisting of all irrational elements need not be nowhere dense; a counterexample is the set of all irrationals (the closure of the irrationals is R). And nowhere dense sets need not have measure zero, such as fat cantor sets.

Your question has little to do with measure theory. As shown in the two answers, you just need $E$ to be uncountable.

You can use this theorem.
Alternatively, assume $\forall x\in E(\forall y\in E(x-y\in\Bbb Q))$.
Let $a$ be an element of $E$ (which must be non-empty).
So $\forall x\in E(x-a\in\Bbb Q)$. But $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x-a\in\Bbb Q\}$ is a translated copy of $\Bbb Q$ and is countable. So $E$ is countable and has measure $0$.

How do we know ${x\in\Bbb R\mid x-a\in\Bbb Q}$ is a translated copy of $\Bbb Q$?

For $x$ in $\Bbb R$, $x-a\in\Bbb Q$ if and only if $\exists y\in \Bbb Q(x-a=y)$ which is equivalent to $\exists y\in \Bbb Q(x=y+a)$.

It's a little simpler to say that $E \subseteq { x \mid \exists q \in \Bbb Q (x = a+q) }$, so $E$ is a subset of a countable set, and therefore is itself countable.

Yes, there are fat cantor sets which are nowhere dense, but which have positive measure. So it is invalid to argue that nowhere dense implies measure zero.
Let's suppose that there is some measurable subset $E$ of $R$ such that all numbers in $E$ are equivalent mod $\mathbb{Q}$. (i.e. $|x-y|$ is a rational number for all $x,y\in E$.) Then, fixing $z\in E$, we note that all other elements of $E$ are translations of $z$ by some rational number. Concretely: if for every $x\in E$, we have $x-z\in \mathbb Q$ then there is some rational number $q$ for which $x=q+z$. So the map which sends each $q\in \mathbb Q$ to $z+q$ in $\mathbb R$ is a surjection onto $E$. But then $E$ is at most countable. So $E$ must have measure zero.
But this is all we need, as contraposition gives the result.
